# Questions not repeating 10 times with the score at the end

Tags: python, for-loop, output

I am creating a maths quiz in python. I have made the code so that 10 random questions are being asked. At the end of the quiz it should tell the user the quiz has finished and how much they scored in the quiz but I'm having some difficulty in that. Here is a section of my code where I believe I have gone wrong:

```
def askquestion():
    score = 0
    opslist = {operator.add: "+", operator.sub: "-", operator.mul: "x"} #All operators that can be chosen
    num1,num2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)        #Two Random Numbers          
    ops = random.choice(list(opslist.keys()))        # random operators from oplist keys                        
    ActualAnswer = (ops(num1,num2))                #Answer for my quiz                                
    score = 0
    print(num1,opslist[ops],num2)           # Question for my quiz        
    userAns = (int(input("Enter answer:")))
    if userAns == ActualAnswer:         #If the user's answer matches the Actual Answer     
        print("Correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        score = score - 0

    for i in range (10):
        askquestion()  

    print ("The quiz has finished")
    print ("Today you achieved a score of" ,score,"out of 10")
```

Say I move the for loop below the last print so that it is not part of the `def askquestion():` I get an output like this:

```
2 + 6
Enter answer:8
Correct
The quiz has finished
Today you achieved a score of 1 out of 10
6 x 3
Enter answer:18
Correct
The quiz has finished
Today you achieved a score of 1 out of 10
5 x 1
Enter answer:5
Correct
The quiz has finished
Today you achieved a score of 1 out of 10
```

If I keep it in the position it is along with the rest of the code it just doesn't ask me the questions and the program stops after the introduction where the program asks for the name. If you think you need the rest of the code please provide an e-mail address but I am positive I've gone wrong in the code provided.

Q.) What should I change so that when the 10 questions are over the score is outputted **at the end**

Comment: Provide the full definition of your askquestion function.

Comment: michealpri i've edited it, see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems in your code. Here's is what I came up with to fix it.

```
import operator
import random

def askquestion():
  score = 0
  opslist = {operator.add: "+", operator.sub: "-", operator.mul: "x"} #All operators that can be chosen
  num1,num2 = random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10)        #Two Random Numbers          
  ops = random.choice(list(opslist.keys()))        # random operators from oplist keys                        
  ActualAnswer = (ops(num1,num2))                #Answer for my quiz                                
  score = 0
  print(num1,opslist[ops],num2)           # Question for my quiz        
  userAns = (int(input("Enter answer:")))
  if userAns == ActualAnswer:         #If the user's answer matches the Actual Answer     
    print("Correct")
    return 1
  else:
    print("Incorrect")
    score = score - 0
  return 0

totalScore = 0
for i in range (10):
  totalScore += askquestion()  

print ("The quiz has finished")
print ("Today you achieved a score of" ,totalScore,"out of 10")
```

All of your `askQuestion()` function is good, but variables in functions aren't global, so you need to return it to use it later. Instead of having to keep track of the variable created in the function, you can use a global variable `totalScore` to keep track of the score. `askQuestion()` now returns a 1 when the answer is right and a 0 if the answer is wrong.

Now you need to move the for loop out of `askQuestion()` so it works. The `for i in range(10):` works but you could also use a `while` loop like this:

```
totalScore = 0
i = 0
while i < 10:
    totalScore += askQuestion()
    i += 1
```

In the loop, you are using the global variable `totalScore` to keep track of the 1's and 0's return by `askQuestion()`. At the end, you are just printing the score.

Comment: michealpri do you have an email, so i can email you my code as i have a few problems i dont want to ask on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your if/else blocks inside your askquestion() function or after it in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking you want something like this

```
   def ask_question():
          #your question logic here
          #increment score

   def print_summary(score):
           print "Today you got a score of..."

   for i in range(10):
         ask_question()

    print_summary()
```

Define functions that perform each task in your program then indicate the order your program should flow through those functions.

What you really want to do is encapsulate the quiz logic in a class with ask question, administer quiz and print summary methids .